# Template_redirect works, but headers aren't sent when checking via cURL

Tags: hooks, redirect, template-redirect

I'm creating a 307 redirect to maintenance page for when my site goes through maintenance.

My PHP class is included in functions.php, and gets instantiated immediately.

In my __construct, I call:

```
add_action('template_redirect', [ $this, 'redirectToMaintenance' ] );
```

Then my redirectToMaintenance() method looks like this:

```
public function redirectToMaintenance() {

 $pageToLoad = get_the_permalink(123); // for test page ID

 header( "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect" );
 header("Location: ". $pageToLoad );
 die();

}
```

This works perfectly, but if I try:

```
curl -iL https://example.com
```

No redirects are detected.

Same thing when I check via wheregoes.com.

I've tried redirecting with hooks other than "template_redirect" but they don't seem to work well.

Any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: so your redirect works as expected, it's just the curl output that doesn't show it? Are you sure it's not that curl did see it but followed the redirect and is showing you the headers for the redirected second request?

Comment: Correct -- as a result I don't know how it will look to search engines. It's showing the headers of the original page requested -- not the redirected page.

Comment: have you tried google search console/cloud console to check directly? Search engines have diagnostic tools that you can test and know for certain if they're directed, though I would expect them to redirect fine. Also HTTP 1.1 is old, are you sure your server isn't using HTTP2? Is there a reason you manually redirected instead of using a `wp_redirect()` call?

Comment: Switched to wp_redirect(). For what it's worth, in my browser's network tab I do see a 307 status code come from the GET request on the original requested URL